# Deploying git repo to "production" server

Tags: linux, git, github, sftp

I have a git repo where a group of developers and I are collaborating on project code. occasionally, we'd like to copy the git repo to a VPS (setup as Linux server) that has an external IP address (`w.x.y.z`).

I can go into an SFTP client and navigate up the folder hierarchy to the server root and then navigate down to /var/www/ (server web root) to drop my files in but I'd like to deploy to the server through the command line instead.

My goal is to configure the Linux server as a remote git directory but don't know how to go about navigating up the file hierarchy to have git recognize that the remote branch repo needs to go into /var/www/.

Brief search has uncovered `git remote add origin username@w.x.y.z` then use `git push origin`.

It seems that connecting this way to `w.x.y.z` will land me at the home folder of 'username', not the root web directory (/var/www/) when accessed via the browser.

Does anyone have insight into how I should go about setting up  a remote directory for deploying a git repo to a "production" server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be doing this a rather non-obvious way. I think what you want to do is copy the git repo to somewhere else (the vps server). The standard way to achieve this is `git clone`.

In your `/var/www/` directory or an appropriate subdirectory thereof, do:

```
git clone [URL-FROM-GITHUB]
```

That will clone the git repository to your VPS. You can then update it with

```
git pull
```

could script this with

```
ssh my.vps.server 'cd /var/www/whatever && git pull'
```

However, normally you don't want the entire project in '/var/www/...' because that would also put stuff you did not mean to deploy there, e.g. the `.git` directory. Hence perhaps better to clone the repo within your home directory, and make a small script to `rsync` the appropriate `/var/www/` directory against your repo, using `--exclude` to remove files you don't want, or just `rsync`-ing a subdirectory of the repo.

Comment: Thanks. I believe this is what I was looking for. I'll look into rsync to see if I can get that working for what I need

Comment: I have a question about this, why would I `git pull` if I can just `rsync` directly to `/var/www/` directory?

Comment: @AliElkhateeb `rsync` will pull whatever happens to be in the working copy at the time, rather than the head commit from master. Running a git repo on the web server also allows you to easily roll back to a different commit.